# Response in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code segment.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
    };
```

How can I check whether 'response' is empty or not? Even though the function doesn't show any error, 'response' contains a not null value. My objective is to navigate to some other page if 'response' doesn't contain any error messages. Can you please tell me a solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check whether the response is valid (ie, the page exists), check the `status` property:

```
if(ajaxRequest.status == 200) ; //... valid
```

If you want to check whether response is empty or not, test it in a condition `response != ""`. Because an empty string evaluates to false in a logical expression, the `!= ""` is not necessary.

```
if(ajaxRequest.responseText) ; //not empty
```

Comment: It's worth checking for other success responses than 200, like `if (ajaxRequest.status >= 200 && ajaxRequest.status < 300)` - also what if `ajaxRequest.responseText` is `0`? You should do `if (ajaxRequest.responseText === '')`

Comment: @Achu If your question is fully answered, use the **[Accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)** feature. Your previous question has also received the correct answer, although it's not accepted.